# Digital Signature Export from Etoken to pfx file

Tags: digital-signature

I am trying to export a digital signature from etoken in .pfx format. When I export the private key, it gives an error saying "Export failed. Key not valid for use in the specified state."
I am using Jailbreak for exporting the signature. The operating system is windows xp.

Answer (score 2):

Signature is a product of applying a private key to the data using a certain algorithm. They are not usually contained in tokens.

You probably want to obtain a certificate with an associated private key from the device. This is almost always prohibited -- private keys are not exportable and they are protected in hardware (i.e. vendors take special measures to prevent extraction of the key using hardware approaches, not just software export).

Comment: Agree with @Eugene, the primary purpose of a hardware token is to prevent the export or migration of private key. The devices are designed to require the token to be present/connected for any software to sign or encrypt with hardware-protected private keys.

Comment: I thought the purpose of the Token was to prevent duplication that could be used to code sign for Windows 10. I have successfully exported my eToken to a .cer and .p7b cert but for jar signing it looks like I need a .pfx. Well that is where I am up to so far.

Comment: @WilliamK right, you have exported only the public part. And the token won't let you export the private part (most likely). However, for JAR signing you don't need to export anything. Instead, use one of these commands to sign the JAR:

%JAVABIN%\jarsigner.exe -storetype PKCS11 -keystore NONE -storepass "StorePassHere" -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerArg {filename}.cfg {file_to_sign} {"SubjectName as string"}
or
%JAVABIN%\jarsigner.exe -storetype Windows-MY -keystore NONE {file_to_sign} {"SubjectName\CN"}

Comment: Jar signing with the eToken just hangs. Still waiting to hear back from GlobalSign.

Comment: @WilliamK if you received the token from GlobalSign, then yes, the question is for them to answer. However, in general, it's a problem of the token (device and its drivers) or your setup of it.

Comment: Jar signing from the eToken was successful from another PC (Win10), which initially gave an error message that Win7 did not. From there I established an error with the timestamp link.